# LZ4 giving different compressed data for different languages

Tags: compression, lz4

I am using lz4 to compress a data, that data is consumed by different application written in Java, Go & Python.
Thankfully, libraries are available for the said languages.

My source data compression is done using Golang and the languages are decompressing and using it.

However, the issue is all of them gives different compressed data base64 string for same string.
So the receiving applications are unable to get the expected data.

e.g  `Swift.lz4_compress("ABC") != Java.lz4_compress("ABC")`

Is this an expected behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not unexpected. What's specified is the format of the compressed data, not the exact algorithm used to determine the "best" encoding. As long as it decompressed back to the same thing, it's OK. The compressed stream (and the level of compression) will differ based on the complexity and sophistication of the specific algorithm used, as well as various tradeoffs (e.g. time or space vs compression level).